# Degrees around X and Y between a camera's forward vector and a vector from the camera's position to the origin

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

I can do the following to get the overall `angle` between where I am looking with my camera and the origin:

```
var targetDirection = Vector3.zero - Camera.main.transform.position;
var angle = Vector3.Angle(targetDirection, Camera.main.transform.forward);
```

But how can I instead get the degrees around the X-axis and the degrees around the Y-axis that make up this angle?

Comment: There aren't "X and Y components of the angle." That value is just how many degrees (or Radians) between the two vectors. If you want the "degrees around the X axis" and "degrees around the Y axis" separately, then that's a different question.

Comment: @Draco18s Yeah, that's exactly what I want. I will edit the question for you. Mind you, I did say components in my question, but I guess this is more of an interpretation thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out using plane projection:

```
var targetDirection = Vector3.zero /* Note: Can replace Vector3.zero with another target. */ - Camera.main.transform.position;
var horizontalPlaneNormal = Vector3.Cross(targetDirection, Vector3.right);
var vectorX = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(Camera.main.transform.forward, horizontalPlaneNormal);
var angleX = Vector3.SignedAngle(targetDirection, vectorX, horizontalPlaneNormal);
var verticalPlaneNormal = Vector3.Cross(targetDirection, Vector3.up);
var vectorY = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(Camera.main.transform.forward, verticalPlaneNormal);
var angleY = Vector3.SignedAngle(targetDirection, vectorY, verticalPlaneNormal);
Debug.LogFormat("AngleX: {0}, AngleY: {1}", angleX, angleY);
```

**Explanation**:

The camera can look anywhere, and be positioned anywhere. To get an accurate angle, you need to project the vector of where the camera is looking onto a plane. To construct the horizontal or vertical plane you need, you will need to use the cross product to get its normal in order to use the `ProjectOnPlane()` method. Finally, you can get a signed angle between your two vectors (your target direction vector and the projected vector relative to where the camera is looking). The code speaks for itself. Cheers!